# Неправильно вычисляет контрольную сумму TCP (tcp checksum)

Tags: linux, kernel, tcp

```
    netfilter_ops_out.hook                  =       main_hook2;//исходящий
    netfilter_ops_out.pf                    =       PF_INET;
    netfilter_ops_out.hooknum               =       3; 
    netfilter_ops_out.priority              =       NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
----------------------------------------------------
struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)(skb_network_header((skb)) + ip_hdrlen((skb)));
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);   
----------------------------------------------------
if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {     
    printk(KERN_ALERT "----------------ИСХОДЯЩИЙ ПАКЕТ TCP---------------------\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM IP old: %u.\n",iph->check); 
    iph->daddr=in_aton("192.168.245.133");
    iph->check = 0;
    ip_send_check(iph);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM IP new: %u.\n",iph->check);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "INFO: CHECKSUM TCP old: %u.\n",tcph->check);
    datalen = skb->len - (iph->ihl << 2); 
    tcph->check = 0;
    tcph->check =csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr,datalen, iph->protocol,csum_partial((char *)tcph, datalen, 0));
```

Wireshark на винде показывает все время неправильную контрольную сумму tcp пакета.
На забугорном stackoverflow у всех работает, после skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY; в конце расчета контрольной суммы. 
НО! Контрольная сумма же неправильная..
UPD: Изначально проверял я так: банально пересчитывал контрольную сумму исходящшего tcp пакета с машины Linux на винду. TCP offloading включен на винде, выключен на linux.

Comment: А тот метод, что использует `linux/net/netfilter/nf_nat_proto_tcp.c` не подходит ?

Comment: obj-m += hello.o

all:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

это makefile, подгружаю из /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic
я скачал linux-4.6-rc3 из kernel.org
Мне нужно в makefile просто указать на эту папку? или достаточно все из linux-4.6-rc3 скопировать в /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic?

Comment: У вас ядро то какое ? Для начала поставьте исходники именнно того ядра, которое используется в системе и headers к нему

Comment: 3.19.0-32-generic - я поставил linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic, linux/net/netfilter/nf_nat_proto_tcp.c там нет, проверял locate nf_nat_proto_tcp.c устанавливал Linux mint 17.3 Cinnamon 32-bit.

Comment: Ну так в headers конечно нет. Вы ставьте целиком исходники ядра. В gentoo пакет называется просто linux (из раздела sys-kernel) как в других дистрибутивах - не знаю. Но исходники всегда можно взять на kernel.org

Comment: Спасибо, буду искать.

Comment: Я понял, выдает неправильную контрольную сумму для 443 порта, все остальные контрольные суммы выдает без проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datalen = skb->len - (iph->ihl << 2); 
tcph->check = 0;
tcph->check =csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr,datalen, iph->protocol,csum_partial((char *)tcph, datalen, 0));
skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY;
```

Все верно считает, Wireshark на другой машине не ругается, ругается только на tcp пакет по 443 порту!